# Android Problem with scrollviews and image resizing

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview

This is my main.xml that I use, and the two images in the myImage_Main and myImage_Main2 are messed up.
Is there a way to set the android:layout_width to the size of the bitmap? or do i just set it to 500px which is about the size of the screen?

Example what i want :

```
Scroll view -------------------------------
|
|               Image 1 Full Sized on Screen
|
|
|               Bottom of screen
___________________________________________
|              Not yet on screen, but  
|           Scroll down to see Image 2    |
|
|
|
|_____________________________________________|
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


     <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_gravity="top"
        >
        <Button android:id="@+id/myButton_Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_search"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/myButton_Save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_save"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />
    </LinearLayout>

     <EditText
     android:id="@+id/myEdittext"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     />
 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_width= **Right here I want to get the size of the image i use as the width**
 android:layout_height=**Right here I want to get the size of the image i use as the height**
 android:fillViewport="true"
 android:scrollY="100px"
 >
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
 android:layout_width=**Right here I want to get the size of the image i use as the width**
 android:layout_height=**Right here I want to get the size of the image i use as the height**
 android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myImage_Main"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   />
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/myImage_Main2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   />
   </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How much space is left for your ScrollView? And, have you try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `wrap_content` for all of those. When the layout is inflated in `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`, it will determine the exact amount of width needed to display all of its child views. You'll need to set `scaleType="none"`, however. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, so if I'm misunderstanding the question, please clarify.